Why does "Convert to New TypeScript Project Experience" create a nuget.config file?
I have a njsproj project in Visual Studio. It is exclusively Typescript. I tried to do the option of "Convert to New TypeScript Project Experience" and that successfully makes an esproj file. That's all well and good. But it also makes a nuget.config file. I don't understand why this would exist in the context of a JS/TS project. What is this supposed to do and what does nuget have to do with JS/TS?
